# Abrir BLOB em php

Tags: php, java, android

Eu tenho um campo do tipo BLOB para salvar imagens no meu mysql, a imagem vem de um APP android via POST, do jeito que a string BLOB chega eu salvo no banco.
Quando eu vou tentar mostrar o conteudo desse BLOB em uma pagina, fica tudo em branco.
Código PHP que eu uso para mostrar a imagem:

```
<?php   
    //header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    include('conexao.php');
    include('funcoes.php');
    $sqlImagem = "SELECT foto from combustivel_abastece;";
    $consultaImagem = mysql_query($sqlImagem, $connection) or die (print "Erro TABELA consulta imagem <br>".mysql_error());
    if ((mysql_num_rows($consultaImagem) > 0)) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consultaImagem)) {
            echo '<img src="data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['foto'] ) .'" /> <br>';
        }   
    }               

?>
```

Detalhe: a mesma string que eu envio para o mysql, se eu tentar mostrar no APP Android, ela funciona

Answer (score 1):

Tente desta forma:

```
<?php   
    //header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    include('conexao.php');
    include('funcoes.php');
    $sqlImagem = "SELECT foto from combustivel_abastece;";
    $consultaImagem = mysql_query($sqlImagem, $connection) or die (print "Erro TABELA consulta imagem <br>".mysql_error());
    if ((mysql_num_rows($consultaImagem) > 0)) {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($consultaImagem)) {
            echo '<img src="data:image/bmp; base64(data:image/bmp;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['foto'] ) .'" /> <br>';
        }   
    }               

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu resolvi o problema.
O erro não estava só no php. Eu precisava converter a string para base64 antes de enviar para o mysql
Dessa maneira meu codigo php ficou da seguinte maneira

```
echo '<img style="width:100;height:100" src="data:image/png;base64, '. $row['foto']  .'" /> <br>';
```